# How to convert an image to Avro format in Hadoop?

Tags: avro

I want to convert *.jpg files to the avro format and vice versa.
The exact requirement is:

1. convert all the *.jpg images to avro format.
2. process the images and remove the duplicates by help of avro MR jobs.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Using Avro buys you absolutely nothing in this scenario.  But if you insist on it, here's what you'd need to do.

1. Read the images using [FileInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html) or define your own `InputFormat` that extends [FileInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/FileInputFormat.html) if you want to do the conversion in the cluster (I'm not aware of any InputFormat you could use out of the box).
2. Then store the raw bytes an Avro record that is nothing more than something like

```js
{
   "type":"record",
   "namespace":"com.mycompany",
   "name":"JPEG",
   "fields":[
      {
         "name":"TheBytes",
         "type":"bytes"
      },
   ]
}
```

3. Then use the bytes as the key (or use [AvroKey](https://avro.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/avro/mapred/AvroKey.html) since it will use the fields to do the comparison), the shuffle will group the duplicates, then you can use the reducer to filter out the duplicates.  This approach will **not** identify images that are similar as duplicate.  Even changing the metadata on the file will alter the bytes and cause it to not match.

In general, I think this is an ill-advised requirement.  You might consider working with the data using something like [HIPI](http://hipi.cs.virginia.edu/) instead.